# loop invariant of selection sort algorithm

Tags: sorting, loop-invariants, program-correctness

I am asked to write an C code Selection Sort algorithm and use loop invariant to show its correctness.

```
We are given array A[1...n] of n integers. (Indexation 1 for clearance. In my code it starts at 0)

int i, j, min_index, temp;
for(i=0; i<n-1; i++) {
    min_index = i;
    for(j=i+1; j<n; j++)
       if(A[j] < A[min_index])
           min_index = j;
 temp = A[i];
 A[i] = A[min_index];
 A[min_index] = temp;
}
```

I see we need to 2 loop invariants to prove correctness of the algorithm. 
Loop Invariant for the second inner loop:

```
     At the start of each iteration of for loop, A[min_index] is the smallest element in A[i, j).

     Initialization: before the first iteration i = min_index and j = i + 1. A[min_index] is the only
       element in A[i, i+1) which is trivially the smallest element. 

     Maintenance: Next, we tackle the second part: showing that each iteration maintains the loop 
      invariant. suppose for j loop invariant holds, that is, A[min_index] is the smallest in 
      A[i, j). for the next iteration of loop where j = j + 1, if A[j + 1] < A[min_index] we update 
      min_index to j + 1. Now A[min_index] is the new min in A[i, j+1).  Else we do nothing. in this 
      case A[min_index] remains the smallest in A[i, j+1). in both cases loop invariant hold true.

     Termination: condition which cause to terminate loop is j = n. now by termination condition and 
      loop invariant we can conclude A[min_index] is the smalles in A[i, j = n) which means we found 
      minimum element A[min_index] in the subarray A[i, n-1].
```

Now we've proved correctness of second for loop, which find the smallest element in subarray A[i, n-1]. Let's write loop invariant for the outer loop:

```
     At the start of each iteration of loop, A[0, i) contains i smallest elements of A[0...n-1] but in 
      sorted order. 

     Initialization: prior to the first iteration of loop i=0. A[0,i) is empty subarray and predicate 
      is vacuously true.

     Maintenance: We need to show that each iteration maintains the invariant property. Assume for i 
      invariant holds. A[0, i) contains i smallest elements of original array in sorted order. at the 
      next iteration i = i + 1. we can definitely conclude by first loop invariant that A[min_index]      
      will be the smallest element in A[i, n). Since we know predicate is true for i, we can say that   
      A[0, i) is sorted, and we swap A[i] with A[min_index]. we're done. A[0, i+1) contains i+1 
      smallest elements of original array in sorted order.

     Termination: Termination condition which is i=n-1 along with invariant implies that A[0, n-1) 
      contains n-1 smallest elements of array in sorted order. Since A[0, n-1) contains the n-1 smallest 
      elements of the array, automatically the last element which is A[n-1] is greater than or equal to 
      all elements in A[0, n-1) and therefore is in the correct place in sorted array.
```

I think it's clear from the proof why do we need to operate on n-1 elements of the array. So I've described what I've done myself, but I have doubts about proof. Is there any bogus in proof or can you suggest something better to improve parts of it? I appreciate your answers.